# Помогите со знаками препинания в предложении:

Tags: пунктуация

Холод усиливается ветром (?) этой ночью (?) тёмной и страшной.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложение нужно редактировать (изменить структуру).

Варианты:

Холод **усилится** этой ночью, тёмной и страшной.

**Этой ночью, тёмной и страшной,** холод усиливается ветром.